# I get an error when using plot(rect(....)) in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot sea level dat in R and would like to plot the errors as rectangles. I am using the code shown below. It plots the rectangles in the plot box in R. However, when I use the graphics window (window()) I do not get a plot.

```
  ID Mindepth middepth maxdepth Calib7min Calib7max  age  sey sex Class   
1  1   -11.63   -11.30   -10.97      7725      7935 7835 0.33 100     1    
2  2   -13.35   -13.00   -12.65      8025      8170 8100 0.35  70     1    
3  4   -14.24   -14.08   -13.92      8180      8310 8240 0.16  70     1    
4  5   -16.23   -16.07   -15.91      8390      8420 8405 0.16  15     2    
5  6   -14.57   -14.41   -14.25      8175      8305 8230 0.16  75     2    
6  7   -15.67   -15.53   -15.39      8400      8450 8420 0.14  30     2

attach(li.dat)    
xleft <- Calib7min    
xright <- Calib7max    
ytop <- maxdepth    
ybottom <- Mindepth    
x<-age    
y<-middepth

windows()    
plot.window(xlim=range(7800:9000), ylim = range(-16:-10))    
plot(x, y, type = "n", ylim = range(-16:-10), ylab="", xlab="", axes=F)    
title(ylab = "Relative Sea Level (m)", col="red")    
axis(side=2, col="red", col.axis = "Red")    
plot(rect(xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop, border ="red", lwd = 2,))
```

I get the following error when I try to do either:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I have tried using

```
plot.window(xlim=range(7800:9000), ylim = range(-16:-10))
```

Does anybody have any suggestions what the problem is and how I can get around it?

Comment: why `range(7800:9000)` and not just `c(7800, 9000)` ?

Comment: Thanks Cath, No reason. I thought they were the same thing. Perhaps not